# Java: Cannot access methods from a different class

Tags: java

First Class: Graph.java

```
public class Graph {

    public void generateGraph(int VertexNum, int numOfEdges) throws ZeroVerticesException, DisjointGraphException{
        //Statements
    }
    //More methods    
}
```

Second class : prims.java

```
public class prims {

    Graph g=new Graph();

    g.generateGraph(10,20); // Error here

}
```

The error shows as: "Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration"

Why can't i access the method after creating an instance of graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, your code statements should be part of some **method** or a **block**

In your case, at least main method, if that is your main class.

The code can't just be inside class body, outside any block

Following code should probably help what you are trying to achieve

```
public class prims {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Graph g=new Graph();

        g.generateGraph(10,20); // Error here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it !! I will accept your answer in a while.

Comment: Please don't get in the habit of answering questions that get asked daily. Instead, make an effort to find a duplicate and flag (or vote once you have enough reputation) to close as such.

Comment: Sure @SotiriosDelimanolis